# Can someone explain this type of syntax, and what it is doing?

Tags: java

I am not really sure what is going on in the print statement. More specifically, what does the "&", "?" and ":" do to the formatting in this print statement?

```
 for (int j = 0; j < x; j++) {
            System.out.print((maze[j][i] & 8) == 0 ? "|   " : "    ");
        }
```

Comment: There's also a bitwise mask (`&`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The '&' here is the bitwise operator. And *variable* == *something* ? x : y this is the ternary operator which in the example you can read like this 'If bitwise AND of maze[i][j] with 8 is equal to 0, then print "|  "  else print "  " '

Answer (score 0):

```
(maze[j][i] & 8) == 0 ? "|   " : "    ")
```

evaluates to `"|   "` if the 8-bit of `maze[j][i]` is 0, and `"    "` if it's 1.

`maze[j][i] & 8` does a bitwise AND of the value of `maze[j][i]` and the number 8.  The result will be either 8 (if the value at `maze[j][i]` has a 1 in the bit position corresponding to 8's) or 0 (if it has a 0 there).

If it is zero (`== 0`), then ( `?` )  the expression resolves to the string with the pipe( `"|   "`); otherwise (`:`) it resolves to the string without the pipe (`"    "`).

Answer (score 0):

The & is a [bitwise and](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#AND) (it will be 1 when the eighth bit is 1 in both numbers), the `==` is a boolean conditional and the `?:` is the [ternary conditional expression (jls-15.25)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.25).

```
System.out.print((maze[j][i] & 8) == 0 ? "|   " : "    ");
```

is equivalent to

```
if ((maze[j][i] & 8) == 0) {
  System.out.print("|   ");
} else {
  System.out.print("    ");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's say it is a shortcut if/else condition or they call it ternary operator. It's actually a good way when you want to test some value before printing out something or storing something into a variable. `&` is a bitwise AND operator, it compares the bits of each side. 
`?` is something like THEN, when the condition is true it will do the task inside it,
`:` is `else` it will do the task inside it if the condition is not true

here's a more readable snippet so you can understand what I'm talking about

```
for (int j = 0; j < x; j++) {
    if(maze[j][i] & 8) {
        System.out.print("|   ");
    } else {
        System.out.print("    ");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
System.out.print((maze[j][i] & 8) == 0 ? "|   " : "    ");
```

translates as:

If the value at maze[j][i] has a 0 in the 4th-least-significant bit, then print "|   "; otherwise, print "    ".

& is a bitwise and; it returns 0 if there are no 1 bits in common between the operands.

? : is a ternary operator. It evaluates the truth of the first argument. If true, it executes the second argument; otherwise, it executes the third.

Answer (score 0):

`&` is `bitwise and`.it returns `1` only when `a` and `b` both are `1`

> a and b are `individual bits` in which a number can be represented and can have a truth value of `0` or `1`

e.g for `12 & 13`

> 12    = 1100(in binary)
>
> 13    = 1101(in binary)
>
> 12&13 = 1100

and the statement `x == 0 ? 1 : 2` is called `ternary operators`..if the statement before `?` is true then the first statement (i.e) `1` is printed otherwise `2`..it is equivalent to `if else`..it can be written like

```
if (x == 0) {
   System.out.println(1);
} else {
   System.out.println(2);
}
```

Comment: Saying "& is bitwise and.it returns 1 only when a and b both are 1" is a bit confusing, since `&` operates on individual bits; the `&` operator itself doesn't return 1, but whatever the shared 1-bits add up to.

Comment: i had edited it and written there what is `a` and `b`.. __a and b are individual bits in which a number can be represented and can have a truth value of 0 or 1__ ..is it ok now??